# Strange behavior in cell text localization. Xcode 7 [swift]

Tags: xcode, swift, localization, tableview, uitableview

I'm localizing my App.
I have a Static `TableView` and as sometimes happens I created new things after creating the `Main.strings` file has been created.
Therefore I added new lines as anyone knows.
I have two `Basic` rows in my `TableView` with some text that I want to localize.
The ID of the cell is `wIm-3s-i6y` therefore I did:

```
"wIm-3s-i6y.text" = "My localized text";
```

However the cell does not change its text, keeping its `Base` value.
Any idea why?
Please note that I'm trying to avoid doing this programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the ID in question should not be that of the cell, but rather the ID of the cell's label inside its `contentView`.

In any case, manually editing strings for a storyboard file is not recommended. You can ensure your storyboards have up-to-date corresponding strings files by selecting your project file in your project in Xcode, then Editor -> Export for Localization.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I didn't know that it is not recommended. Thus, I tried what you suggest and I'm getting this error: "Localization failed to read a strings file", perhaps I exported the wrong file.

Comment: I'd recommend deleting the strings file and trying again. If that doesn't help out too much, please attach your project in a bug report at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: I still do not understand how I should implement localization. However, you were right about that my ID code wasn't related to the label but the content view!

Comment: Let me know if you still have any questions regarding localisation. The recommended process is to use Xcode's export functionality to generate .xliff files that are translated (i.e. direct modification of .strings files never needs to be done), and then re-imported into Xcode for each language.

Comment: I didn't know that the recommended process was using export functionality. Perhaps if you have any reference or tutorials I can take a look and learn something

Comment: Right here! https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html